# jQuery: add together two data-values from two select fields and display sum conditionally

Tags: jquery

How to take data-value from two select fields and display the sum of them in div below?

```
<div class="input_field">
    <label>Type</label>
    <select name="select1" class="dropdown dropdown1">
        <option value selected="selected" data-value="0">Select entry type</option>
        <option value="0" data-value="20">Entry 1 (£20)</option>
        <option value="1" data-value="30">Entry 2 (£30)</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input_field">
    <label>T-shirt</label>
    <select name="select2" class="dropdown dropdown2">
        <option value selected="selected" data-value="0">Choose T-shirt</option>
        <option value="none" data-value="0">No t-shirt</option>
        <option value="size-xs" data-value="8">T-shirt size XS</option>
        <option value="size-s" data-value="9">T-shirt size S</option>
        <option value="size-m" data-value="10">T-shirt size M</option>
        <option value="size-l" data-value="11">T-shirt size L</option>
        <option value="size-xl" data-value="12">T-shirt size XL</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="entry_fee">
</div>
```

JQuery code below

```
$('select.dropdown').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var1 = $(".dropdown1 :selected").data('value');
    var2 = $(".dropdown2 :selected").data('value');
    sum = var1 + var2;
    $("#entry_fee").html("£" + sum);
})
```

I would like to hide output if the first dropdown is not selected.

https://jsfiddle.net/gvub1jp0/

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `data` method to work with data attributes in jQuery.

```js
$('select.dropdown').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('select.dropdown :selected').each(function() {
        sum += $(this).data('value');
    });
     $("#output_field").html(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_field">
    <label>Type</label>
    <select id="select1" class="dropdown">
        <option value selected="selected" data-value>Select entry type</option>
        <option value="0" data-value="26">Entry 1 (£26)</option>
        <option value="1" data-value="28">Entry 2 (£28)</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input_field">
    <label>T-shirt</label>
    <select id="select2" class="dropdown">
        <option value selected="selected">Choose T-shirt</option>
        <option value="none" data-value="0">No t-shirt</option>
        <option value="size-xs" data-value="10">T-shirt size XS</option>
        <option value="size-s" data-value="10">T-shirt size S</option>
        <option value="size-m" data-value="10">T-shirt size M</option>
        <option value="size-l" data-value="10">T-shirt size L</option>
        <option value="size-xl" data-value="12">T-shirt size XL</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="output_field">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Newest Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/xosk5e2n/4/)

I think I got what you're going for now..

```js
var currentValue;
var currentTotal = parseInt($("#output_field").html(), 10);
$('#select1, #select2').change(function() {
    currentValue = $(this).find(':selected').data('value');
    lastValue = $(this).data('lastvalue');
    $(this).data('lastvalue', currentValue);
    currentTotal = currentTotal - lastValue + currentValue;
    $("#output_field").html(currentTotal);
    // check that both are selected
    if (!$('#select1 :selected').hasClass('instruction') && !$('#select2 :selected').hasClass('instruction')) {
     $('#output_field').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
     $('#output_field').addClass('hide');
    }
})
```

```css
#output_field.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_field">
    <label>Type</label>
    <select id="select1" class="dropdown" data-lastvalue="0">
        <option value selected="selected" data-value="0">Select entry type</option>
        <option value="0" data-value="26">Entry 1 (£26)</option>
        <option value="1" data-value="28">Entry 2 (£28)</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input_field">
    <label>T-shirt</label>
    <select id="select2" class="dropdown" data-lastvalue="0">
        <option class="instruction" value selected="selected" data-value="0">Choose T-shirt</option>
        <option value="none" data-value="0">No t-shirt</option>
        <option value="size-xs" data-value="10">T-shirt size XS</option>
        <option value="size-s" data-value="10">T-shirt size S</option>
        <option value="size-m" data-value="10">T-shirt size M</option>
        <option value="size-l" data-value="10">T-shirt size L</option>
        <option value="size-xl" data-value="12">T-shirt size XL</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="output_field" class="hide">0</div>
```

[Old Fiddle - to practise on](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/xosk5e2n/)

Comment: @MattT It looks like Musa's does the exact same thing but is much more concise. I did notice it sometimes outputs a 0 at the beginning of the value.

Comment: Mine was bugged too, fixed it by adding `data-value="0"` to 'Select entry type' and 'Choose T-shirt'

Comment: Thanks to Musa's suggestion I made it to work. It's just one more thing, how to hide output if the first select is not not selected

Comment: @MattT Here's a quick way to do it. I suspect there's more you'll want to do but this should get you started. Note you''ll need to add a class to the option you don't want to count as being selected as I did with class="instruction" (or some other way to filter it out) https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/xosk5e2n/4/

Comment: Thanks for you input, I think I know what I need to do

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#output_field").html(
    $("#select1 :selected").attr("data-value") + 
    $("#select2 :selected").attr("data-value")
);
```

If you stored the value in the `value=""` attribute instead of `data-value`, you could access it like this:

`$("#output_field").html($("#select1").val() + $("#select2").val());`